# Xcode6 - How can I Modal Swipe on the new Xcode6 easily?

Tags: xcode6, swipe, deprecated

I have a Problem. The Problem is, that I installed the new xCode 6 and I can't implement the Modal between two View Controllers Scenes anymore in the "Storyboard Segue -> Segue (MODAL)

But when I'm doing that, then a error cames.--> Deprecated-> Modal segues are deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later. :-(

I want only that it swiped (with the finger from right to left) from one View Controller Scene to another View Controller Scene, like in the older Version from xCode 4.5 without many coding.

Can somebody help me ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use present modally. Select the segue got to attributes inspector and then from segue drop down choose present modally instead of Show(e.g. Push)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I did it but it doesn't work. When I push on Run than it doesn't swipe. Maybe I forgot something. Should I change something in the Swip Gesture Recognizer Inspector ?

Comment: The problem is, I want to swift with my finger just to swift. But it doesn't work.